# What are the functions can be used along with Text Area Field?

Tags: custom-field, string

I have a custom text field on custom object where i am using **CONTAINS** to check whether a particular string value is present in that text field or not, same CONTAINS if i try to use on TEXT AREA FIELD, it is not working as expected.

Is there any functions/methods available to check whether particular string value is present in TEXT AREA FIELD.??

Comment: Yes, it works fine when used in apex,but not in formula field @sfdcfox

Answer (score 3):

CONTAINS does work on a LTA field. However, note that CONTAINS is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe, so you may need to also use UPPER or LOWER to make valid checks. All of the TEXT functions (LEN, LEFT, MID, RIGHT, SUBSTITUTE, CONTAINS, UPPER, LOWER, BEGINS, etc) should work. There are a few oddities, like ISBLANK doesn't seem to work correctly, but you can mostly work around those without Apex Code.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Unfortunately as of Now we don't have any option available to check this without using APEX.</s>

You need to use APEX and STRING function to check for the string and you need to write trigger to get same experience.

Based on this Idea [Text Area (Long) Formula support](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrhEAAS) it doesn't look like SF is providing this functionality in near future.

**Update**: Contains indeed works @sfdcfox is correct here

Comment: That's only for a few specific functions. CONTAINS works just fine.